# Select2 Asp.net MVC - Dropdownlist is not valued with initial data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I am using a select2 using MVC 5 and C#.

I'm having trouble with the dropdownlist (select2) loading with initial data of the model.

The items passed in the corresponding binding field properly valued, but they are not shown in select2!

I mean, despite the list of the ViewModel field correctly valued by the controller, the dropdownlist (select2) is not valued correctly, as if the binding model did not work.

Needless to say, I'm googling for 1,5 days.

Fortunately (:)) I have no problem at the loading of select2 with all items, the dropdownlist works correctly even on the post, even I can take the selected items.

Many Thanks to all

P.s: Now that I'm writing, I have a doubt; Could be that select2 doesn't work with List ?

**View**

```
@section scripts{

     ...

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MezziStraSelect, Model.MezziStraOrdinari, new { style = "width: 100%", @class = "form-control" })
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //...

    $("#MezziStraSelect").select2({
        placeholder: "Select one or more items",
        multiple: true,
        allowClear: true
    });

    @if ( Model.MezziStraSelect == null)
    {
        <text>$("#MezziStraSelect").val(null).trigger("change");</text>
    }    
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public Guid[] MezziStraSelect { get; set; }

public MultiSelectList MezziStraOrdinari { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
//Load List MezziStraOrdinari
var _stra = m.GetMezziStraordinari().Select(x => new
{
    id = x.VoceSpesaID,
    desc = x.VoceSpesa
}).ToList();

//view model set field
vm.MezziStraOrdinari = new MultiSelectList(_stra, "id", "desc");

//Load array Mezzi used from item selected


List<Guid> _mezziStraUsati = new List<Guid>();
var elems = dc.ItemSelected.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID.ToString() == _guidSelected);
if (elems!=null)
{
    elems.VociSpese.ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        if (x.VociSpesa.Straordinario == true)
            _mezziStraUsati.Add(x.VoceSpesaViaggioID); //VoceSpesaViaggioID is GUID 
    });
    if (_mezziStraUsati.Count>0)
        vm.MezziStraSelect = _mezziStraUsati.ToArray(); //Guid[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial loading of the Select2 unfortunately the binding cannot set the initial values!

So reading the [Select2 documentation to this link](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items) , I had to proceed with a manual upload via JS.

Practically to try to do an human thing (I hope it is), I created an Extension method in the backend of the Model field

**Extension Method**

```
public static string ToSelect2Array<T>(this T[] values)
{
    var resp = string.Empty;
    values.ToList().ForEach(x => resp += $"'{x.ToString()}',");
    if (resp.Length > 0)
        resp = resp.Substring(0, resp.Length - 1);

    return resp;
}
```

and then in JS client side, I call it like this:

**VIEW (script JS)**

```
        @if ( Model.MezziStraSelect != null)
        {
            <text>
            $("#MezziStraSelect").val([@Html.Raw(Model.MezziStraSelect.ToSelect2Array())]);
            $("#MezziStraSelect").trigger('change');
            </text>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>$("#MezziStraSelect").val(null).trigger("change");</text>
        }
```

This is working quite well, but is it possible that there is no way to get it to bind automatically?

I would be curious to know other solutions, more elegant than this I would be grateful for!